# i want ios 14 and above style inline date picker in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, datepicker, flutter-cupertino

Hey I want to show the ios 14 style date picker ui for my flutter without any external package.i gone through all the forms and website i cant find any solutions. can anyone help me out .i tried lot of packages but its not perfect and good.

[image]

i want the the flutter ui for date picker in the style of IOS 14  inline style date picker

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: u can checkout this package [adoptive_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/adoptive_calendar)

Answer (score 1):

Build it yourself. I know that sounds very harsh and blunt, but I have been looking for other ios style widget packages in flutter before, and was unable to find one on github, pub.dev, stackoverflow, google, etc.

Unless you are wanting any of these widgets: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets/cupertino, then you are likely just out of luck and will need to build it yourself.

For example, I wanted a time picker that looks like the ios short bottom sheet time picker, but I wanted it to only have 3 columns (hour:minute AM/PM - "5:23 PM"), but the CupertinoTimerPicker does not support the AM/PM column that the date picker supports. So, I ripped the package of the CupertinoTimerPicker by putting all the files into my local project.

Now that the files are now in my local directory and not in a package, I can then edit the files to fit my needs. So I spend an afternoon creating an option to have an "Hour:Minute AM/PM" time picker in that package. After that, I was able to use this "custom CupertinoTimerPicker package" that I "made myself."

Here is a list of a few reasons why I recommend to just make it yourself:

1. You can make it as custom as you would like
2. You can add/remove stuff from it easily
3. You will learn more about how the package works
4. You no longer have to rely on the flutter team / package owner to update the package and fix any bugs that may arise. You can just fix them yourself now.

There are probably some more reasons that I could think of, but I need to get back to work now. Let me know if you have any questions!